# Removing mid-division label on subdivisions before zero on ArcGIS Pro scale bar?

Tags: arcgis-pro, scale-bar

Using ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 I have created a scale bar using the Scale Line 1 Metric template with a few modifications like:

- Show one division before zero
- Divisons: 11
- Subdivisions: 10
- Label Position: Below center
- Label: KILOMETRES

It appears as below:

[image]

How can I remove the mid-division (0.5) label (circled above) on the subdivisions before 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as you cannot do that. There are three options for Numbers:

[image]

`Divisions and first mid point` is what you have. There is no option `Divisions` which could make it possible to show labels only for the divisions.

Just as with other layout elements, your only option is to convert your scale bar into a graphic (right-click and choose `Convert To Graphics`) and then ungroup multiple times to get rid of the `0.5` graphics item.

Comment: It looks like there is a Divisions option immediately above the one that you have highlighted in your graphic.  The scroll bar at right is at the bottom three of seven options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to accept the [answer by @AlexTereshenkov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/234754/115) which got me to look harder at the options where, on the SCALE BAR > DESIGN tab in the Numbers group I found that Frequency does (at least at ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1) have a Divisions option (see below).

[image]

Choosing Divisions enabled my scale bar to improve to be:

[image]

For the record there are seven options:

- No labels
- Single label
- Ends (and zero)
- Divisions
- Divisions and first mid point
- Divisions and first subdivisions
- Divisions and all subdivisions

Comment: My bad. How have I missed that! :) I was expecting to see the options in a longer list and now I understood that one has to scroll up to see others.